# Loopback used a reference to a model in another

Tags: node.js, loopbackjs

I work on an application link to a MySQL DB. I have different models, and i want to used a model in another model.js.

for example i have 2 models :

Server.json

```
 {
  "name": "server",
  "base": "PersistedModel",
  "idInjection": false,
  "properties": {
    "idserver": {
      "type": "number",
      "id": true
    },
    "Name": {
      "type": "string"
    },
    "type": {
      "type": "string"
    },
    "cpus": {
      "type": "number"
    },
    "memory": {
      "type": "number"
    },
    "storage": {
      "type": "number"
    },
    "hypervisor": {
      "type": "number"
    },
    "iddatastore": {
      "type": "number"
    },
    "comment": {
      "type": "string"
    }
  },
  "validations": [],
  "relations": {
    "datastores": {
      "type": "hasAndBelongsToMany",
      "model": "Datastore"
    }
  },
  "acls": [],
  "methods": []
}
```

And Datastore.json

```
{
  "name": "Datastore",
    "plural":"Datastores",
  "base": "PersistedModel",
  "idInjection": false,
  "properties": {
    "iddatastore": {
      "type": "number",
      "id": true
    },
    "owner": {
      "type": "number"
    },
    "size": {
      "type": "number"
    },
    "type": {
      "type": "string"
    },
    "name": {
      "type": "string"
    }
  },
  "validations": [],
  "relations": {
    "servers": {
      "type": "hasAndBelongsToMany",
      "model": "server"
    }
  },
  "acls": [],
  "methods": []
}
```

and i would like to get the data from Datastore in Server.js.

i try this way but it doesn't work well :

Server.js

```
var loopback = require('loopback');
var app = module.exports = loopback();

module.exports = function(Server)  {
    Server.on('attached',function(){
       var override = Server.find;

        var Datastore = Server.app.models.Datastore;
        // the problem is here. It seems to return the description of the model when i look for the data

        Server.findById = function(filter,callback){

        var id = arguments[0];
      // this isn't working
        console.log(Datastore.find({where:{"idserver":id}}));

        return override.apply(this, arguments);
        };


       });
};
```

I know it is possible by different way but if it is possible i prefer get the data from Datastore !

Sorry for my english if it is not clear, Do you have any idea ?

Loïc

Answer (score 0):

Try `var Datastore = loopback.getModel('Datastore');`